# Lua - How could I edit the Registry?

Tags: lua, registry

I wanted to know how I could edit the Lua registry?

https://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.1.html
This registry, should include all of the functions, userdata, booleans, and tables.

Comment: "I" being who in this case? If you're in a Lua script, you *can't* touch the registry, period. If you're in C code, then you have complete control over the registry and can do whatever you want with it. So it's not clear what you mean here.

Comment: The registry doesn't store *everything*, it is a hidden table useful for native code to store references to Lua objects. You don't need it in Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua registry is just regular Lua table. There just no reference to it from global scope.
You can e.g. use `debug.getregistry()` function to get it.
But be sure you know what you are doing.
And of course not all libraries stores its data in registry. Some of them use e.g. upvalues or uservalues to store some internal structure. Also any library can change its internals in any time. And most of them I think didn't expect that their data will be changed outside.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that